# Table of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, coordinates

```
typedef struct s_coord
{
    int     ax;
    int     ay;
    int     bx;
    int     by;
    int     cx;
    int     cy;
    int     dx;
    int     dy;
} t_coord;

typedef struct s_piece
{
    t_coord piece[6];
} t_piece;
```

I was wondering if that was the correct manner to create a table of 7 structures?

And how can I set ax, ay etc.. for each table?

ps: making a tetris.

Comment: if you want `7` then you should have `t_coord piece[7];`, so you can use `[0]` up to and including `[6]`, but **not** `[7]` (which afaik is well defined in the standard, but should not be used). Maybe you want to tell us what you are doing to advice you otherwise ?

Comment: What you've got looks fine...

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal way to define a data structure that consists of a table of 6 `t_coord` structures. (If you want 7 of these, change `[6]` to `[7]`.)

You could alternatively define `typedef t_coord[6] a_piece;`. But that would cause surprising behavior sometimes, because arrays behave specially. For example, given `a_piece a1, a2;`, you can't write an assignment `a1 = a2;`, whereas you can assign structures (`t_piece t1, t2; … t1 = t2;`). And arrays decay to pointers in many circumstances, in particular you can't pass or return an array from a function (though you'd normally pass a pointer anyway, given the size of the data structure). Another reason to prefer structures for types that are supposed to remain opaque is that they provide stronger typing: if you accidentally try to assign a `t_piece` to something else, the compiler will complain, whereas the compiler will happily let you assign an `a_piece` to a `t_coord*` (but in fact what you'll have is a pointer to the data and not a copy of the data).

Comment: Shan't I consider '0' as a structure?

Comment: @Slrs No, `0` can be used as a number (integer or floating-point), and as a pointer (where it means `NULL`). It can't be used as a structure, union or array.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 7 you need

```
typedef struct s_piece
{
    t_coord piece[7];
} t_piece;
```

they are referenced as `piece[0]` to `piece[6]` (computers number things from 0)